# Shuffle Deck $7$ times or $8.55$ times?

Tags: random, card-games

Persi Diaconis showed in $1992$ that in order to shuffle a deck of $52$ cards, you need at least $7$ riffle shuffles.

However, in the paper he published, he showed that we needed $\frac{3}{2}\log_2n$ where $n$ is the number of cards in the deck.

$\frac{3}{2}\log_2 52 \approx 8.55$ which is not $7$.

Which answer is right$?$ Should we shuffle $7$ times or $9$ times$?$ I am guessing that the $7$ times comes from a different randomness metric, but I haven't found any article explaining it.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Perhaps $\frac{3}{2}\log_2 n$ is an upper bound, which is only necessary for large $n$? It's been a long time since I read the proof, so I don't remember the details.

Comment: My understanding is that the log term comes from an asymptotic expansion, useful for large $n$.  The $7$ comes from exact calculations.  Here is the article in case you don't have it:  http://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/Riffle.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will check in the article but what you said makes sense.